# Is it wrong to put all Codeigniter translations into one translation file

Tags: codeigniter

Looking fro some advise...

I'm creating a multi-language site with Codeigniter. CI allows me to create several language files, e.g. one per controller and load language files whenever I need them.

For me  it sounds easier to just work with one language file and auto-load it, but this approach doesn't seem to be encouraged. Can anyone tell me if working with one language file (per language) is OK, or should I use a language file per controller ?

Comment: What's your approach for the multilingual site? domain.com/en/ and domain.com/es/? Or switching the language via a cookie, etc?

Comment: The appraoch I use id domain.com/en/..., but that's not the issue. I just want to know wether it's better to have multiple files in ./application/language/english (e.g. one file per controller) or put everything in one language file (e.g. main_lang.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of your file, if size of your single file is too big then for every time you load the file all data for that file will get loaded and your script will take much more memory, in case of big language file it is always to use multiple files and load it when needed, and if your language file is small it is always better to use single file so that you don't need to manage it and simple to use.

Comment: That's what I was thinking also. Right know I keep everything into one file `main_lang.php` (since the file is not that big), but I prefix the different items in the file e.g. `$lang['register.first_name'] = "..."`  (as recommended by the CI user guide)

Comment: If you want to make any parts of your code reusable for future projects, you may want to put those translations into a different file for easy portability.